# Count occurrences of a value in a matrix

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code:
I don't manage to find a right way to count occurrences of number one in a list of arrays like this

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I want to produce an array that contains the sum of ones in each list of my matrix

I tried to use numpy making

```
for m in matrix: 
    y = m.np 
    y.count(1)
```

but the compiler returns me a message like this:
`module 'numpy' has no attribute 'm'`

How can I proceed?

Comment: I would strongly recommend following a good basic Python tutorial, il looks like you are assembling code in a rather random manner. There is no need for numpy here, anyway, so just remove your references to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are counting ones, you can just sum them up:

```
count_ones = [sum(array) for array in matrix]
```

Answer (score 1):

Grow a list with the counts; there is no need of numpy array.

```
ones_per_row = []
for row in matrix: 
    ones_per_row.append(row.count(1))

print(ones_per_row)
```

Output:

```
[7, 2, 2, 7, 8, 3, 7, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very simple and useful way to do the calculation.